# How to calculate count in Django through two m2m levels?

Tags: django, count, subquery, annotate, m2m

I have 3 models like:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    hobby_groups=models.ManyToManyField(
        'HobbyGroup',
        blank=True,
        related_name='group_customers',
    )


class HobbyGroup(models.Model):
    hobbies = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Hobby',
        blank=True,
        related_name='hobby_groups',
    )

class Hobby(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='football')
```

And I need to calculate count of hobbies for each customer.

```
qs = Customer.objects.annotate(
    hobbies_count=Count('hobby_groups__hobbies', distinct=True)
)
```

With distinct it works fine, but very slow.

I've tried to use Subquery.

```
hobbies = Hobby.objects.filter(hobby_groups__group_customers=OuterRef('pk')).values('pk')
hobbies_count = hobbies.annotate(count=Count('*')).values('count')
qs = Customer.objects.annotate(
    hobbies_count=Subquery(hobbies_count)
)
```

But it returns exception 'More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression'

Is there any way to calculate it faster or fix second solution? Because I did similar for backward related models and it worked fine and fast.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom property in your Customer model to do the counting.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    hobby_groups=models.ManyToManyField(
        'HobbyGroup',
        blank=True,
        related_name='group_customers',
    )

    @property
    def count_hobbies(self):
        return Hobby.objects.filter(
            hobby_groups__group_customers=self
        ).distinct().count()
```

Then, if you have an Customer instance, `john` for example, you can call `john.count_hobbies` to get this customer's number of hobbies.

Comment: thx for the answer. I was thinking about adding property, but I think that it won't be faster, because I need to have this field in admin change-list for many instances, so instead of one request, there will be separate request for each instance. But for update/detail page it's fine.

Comment: AFAIK, the property field can be called by each Customer instance. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I've checked your solution. It makes more queries to db, but works faster. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your subquery is almost right, just one of your values needs to be different to get Django to generate the correct group by:

```
hobbies = Hobby.objects.filter(
    hobby_groups__group_customers=OuterRef('pk')
    ).values('hobby_groups__group_customers')

hobbies_count = hobbies.annotate(count=Count('*')).values('count')

qs = Customer.objects.annotate(
    hobbies_count=Subquery(hobbies_count)
)
```

Alternatively, you could use the package [django-sql-utils](https://github.com/martsberger/django-sql-utils) and do it much more simply:

```
from sql_util.utils import SubqueryCount

qs = Customer.objects.annotate(
    hobbies_count=SubqueryCount('hobby_groups__hobbies')
)
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, need to check it.